# Get the value from one window to another window - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the value from the first page to the second page, BUT without `FORM`?

Shall we use

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("").value..
```

But this is working in `popup` window, but I need this for between two pages which redirecting from the first page to the second page.

Comment: curious to know why this is downvoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirecting from one page to another, you MUST use form elements to pass from page to page or use a querystring value.  That is it, Javascript does NOT have any knowledge of the structure of the previous page..

Answer (score 1):

or you can use cookies...

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use GET variables by calling `site.com/index.php?info=value` and escaping the contents of `value`. The URL can be changed dinamically, like so:

```
<input type="text" id="the_value" />
<a href="#" onclick="return updateURL()" id="the_link">Click me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateURL()
{
    document.getElementById('the_link').href =
        'site.com/index2.php?info=' +
        encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('the_value'));
    return true;
}
</script>
```